# Android Library projects and having to manually refresh

Tags: android

If I make changes in my Android Library project I have to manually refresh, and sometimes clean all projects that use the Library.  Is this normal?  Is there a way around this?

Comment: I think it's normal, at least if using Eclipse. That's because the Eclipse's workspace has a cache of the resources that it uses on the project, thus it requires refreshing to 'detect' external changes.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround for this issue. The basic idea is to use custom ant builder, because it has ability to refresh any specific resource or whole workspace on clean, manual build or auto-build.

So here are the steps:

1) Create a simple ant file with one empty stub target:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="android" >
  <target name="refresh" />
</project>
```

2) Name it "lib-refresher.xml" and place it into folder where application's .project file is located.

3) Now go to eclipse, find the project that uses android library (not library project itself).

4) For this project go to: Project -> Properties -> Builder

5) Create new builder, select Ant task, select specified "lib-refresher.xml", select build base folder.

6) ***important*** - Refresh tab of ant builder task select "Specific resources" and select you library dependent project.

7) ***important*** - On Target tabs select "refresh" target for build variants: Clean, Manual Build, Auto Build.

8) ***important*** - Save changes, move your new custom ant builder to the top of builders stack.

Now the whole project is going to refresh just before building and lunching application. This will include all changes made to library project into application project. Which is what was needed.

(This can be done the other way around: library project may refresh whole workspace whenever autobuild is launched. This may be a bit overkill, but may solve some harder cases).

Answer (score 1):

I have booth project in workspace (Android Library and Android App) and when i have made any changes in library i have must refresh project with app, but this fixed my problem:

```
(Application) project properties -> Java Build Path -> Tab Projects
```

and there i have added my android library.

Answer (score 0):

That is true. If your lib builds a jar, a that you have added to the Android project you will need to refresh (you can also just right click and refresh on the external jar reference also to save time).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue a couple weeks ago. I didn't find the solution I wanted, which was to modify the sources directly in the library project and the dependent projects automatically refresh, but I did find something better than the chaos of constantly refreshing and cleaning.

The best way that I could find was to use the linked library folder from the dependent project being worked on, that way the project sees the changes live. When jumping to another dependent project, you'll still need to refresh the files that were changed in the other project (usually just the src folder). You may also need to refresh the library project if you want to make direct changes. It might not sound like much of a help, but if you spend large chunks of time in a single dependent project (as has been my case so far), it really does help.

Comment: Your method is the old method used to share code between projects. The problem with it is that you lose the ability to share resources. The whole point of using libraries in the first place is to allow for sharing resources (and thus the distribution of .jar libraries bundled with resources).